# Camera2 api switch camera to normal and b&white

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-camera2

I am new to camera2 api to develop this module, I have jni files encoded in c and am developing a normal to b&w camera. The camera is like this when switch to b&w  is anyone done this in camera2 api?

[image]

Comment: Not clear! are you looking for a black and white camera to open inside your app?

Comment: i mean am developing a camera which i could switch to normal view to b&w, but it uses open gl to generate it, for more reference about the b&w looks click the image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! So what you are looking for is to change the mode of your camera

In order to achieve this you can use Camera.Parameters,You can use the EFFECT_MONO(monochrome) from the color effects to get black & white images...

To make camera parameters take effect, applications have to call  `Camera#setParameters(Camera.Parameters)`.
For example, after `Camera.Parameters#setWhiteBalance`is called, white balance is not actually changed until `Camera#setParameters(Camera.Parameters)` is called with the changed parameters object. Below is a sample code for your reference

```
mCameraDevPara.setColorEffect(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
mCameraDev.setParameters(mCameraDevPara);
```

For camera2api these you can achieve by `CaptureRequest` , it has method `CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE` A special color effect to apply.

> When this mode is set, a color effect will be applied to images
>   produced by the camera device. The interpretation and implementation
>   of these color effects is left to the implementor of the camera
>   device, and should not be depended on to be consistent (or present)
>   across all devices.

For more ref [GO here.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/core/java/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.java)

**Tip:** 
Different devices may have different camera capabilities, such as picture size or flash modes. The application should query the camera capabilities before setting parameters.
For example, the application should call

> `Camera.Parameters#getSupportedColorEffects()`

before calling

> `Camera.Parameters#setColorEffect(String)`

. 
If the camera does not support color effects,

> `Camera.Parameters#getSupportedColorEffects()`

will return null.

Comment: am using camera2 api the new version of camera base on android documentation